Array of SObject to flow-input-variables in LWC lightning-flow
I invoke a flow from an LWC component.
I just want to pass an array of Contact to the flow from LWC (in the js below, the 3rd variable).
What should be the type that we should use in the inputVariables for SObject arrays?
html
<template>
    <lightning-flow
        flow-api-name='Survey_customers',
        flow-input-variables={inputVariables}
    >
    </lightning-flow>
</template>

js
get inputVariables() {
    return [
        {
            name: 'OpportunityID',
            type: 'String',
            value: '<Opportunity.Id>'
        },
        {
            name: 'AccountID',
            type: 'String',
            value: '<Opportunity.AccountId>'
        },
        {
            name: 'ContactList',
            type: 'SObject[]',
            value: '<Contact[]>'
        },

    ];
}

When I use type: 'SObject[]', the following is the error:
The dataType SObject[] for argument ContactList is not a valid data type. 


Have you tried with just type: 'SObject'?

@PhilW Just tried it, that works!.

The documentation isn't particularly clear on the subject, simply stating:

You can map only these types and their associated collection types between flows and custom Lightning web components.

However, you set the type for the input variable to the singular version of the required type, even for collection variables.
Since you want to pass a collection of SObject records in this case, you need to simply specify:
        {
            name: 'ContactList',
            type: 'SObject',
            value: '<Contact[]>'
        },

